# Zend Framework 2 - Why i can't override MvcEvent's MatchRoute?

Tags: php, events, request, zend-framework2, routes

i would like to match all requests where user is unlogged to controller `Admin\Controller\Sign` and action `in`. I wrote this code in `onBootstrap()` method in `Module.php` file :

```
if (!$authService->hasIdentity()) {
    $routeMatch = new RouteMatch(
        array(
            'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Sign', 
            'action'     => 'in'
        )
    );

    $event->setRouteMatch($routeMatch);
}
```

I don't get any errors, but code doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the application route event (MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE) is triggered after the (MvcEvent::EVENT_BOOTSTRAP). 
Which means even if you're setting the route match at the bootstrap level, the application is going to override it with the route match of the request after the MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE.

If you want to avoid this overriding you need to add a listener for the route event with a very low priority to make sure it will not be overridden:

`$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'onRouteEvent'), -1000000);`

Note : the onRouteEvent would be the method of your Module class that handles the route event (similar to your code).

If you want to short-circuit your application running at the bootstrap level, what you can do is to send the headers with redirection code to the client:

```
//get the url of the login page (assuming it has route name 'login')
$url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'login'));
$response=$e->getResponse();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
$response->setStatusCode(302);
$response->sendHeaders();
```

Comment: Instead of low priority, you can use higher priority and `$e->stopPropagation(true);` if you want to override the normal behavior. It should save having to process the route twice. http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.EventManager.Event.html#stopPropagation

Comment: if you want to include an action you can use it like this, on the assemble part followed by the route name `$url = $e->getRouter()->assemble([
                    'action' => 'login'
                ], [
                    'name' => 'Home'
                ]);`

Answer (score 1):

add a route entry sign_in as below in the routes section of the module.config.php under admin module

```
'sign_in' => array(
    'type'    => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/admin/sign/in',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'sign',
            'action'     => 'in',
        ),
    ),
),
```

and call the route in the controller like this

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute('sign_in');
```